# Javascript with THREE JS reference in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, three.js

I'm playing with Angular but can't wrap my head around the following problem.

I want to use a javascript code (SunLight.js from the repository https://github.com/antarktikali/threejs-sunlight) in my Angular project.

But this Sunlight.js uses THREE from Three.js. When I call this SunLight javascript object in my Typescript code I see an error the THREE object is undefined. See image below.

How can I let SunLight.js get access to the three module in my Angular project?

[image: Error log]

**This is my setup:**

I'm including the SunLight.js in a services folder

[image: SunLight.js in folder structure]

In angular.json I define the SunLight.js script reference

[image: angular.json ref to SunLight Script]

In my typeScript file I use it as follow and seems to find the SunLight object.

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is the SunLight.js code from repository https://github.com/antarktikali/threejs-sunlight

```
SunLight = function (
    coordinates_,
    north_,
    east_,
    nadir_,
    sun_distance_ = 1.0
) {
THREE.Object3D.call( this );
this.type = "SunLight";

// Latitude and longtitude of the current location on the world
// Measured as decimal degrees. North and east is positive
this.coordinates = new THREE.Vector2();
this.coordinates.copy( coordinates_ );

// The unit vector that is pointing the north in the scene
this.north = new THREE.Vector3();
this.north.copy( north_ );

// The unit vector that is pointing the east in the scene
this.east = new THREE.Vector3();
this.east.copy( east_ );

// The unit vector that is pointing the ground in the scene, same as gravity
this.nadir = new THREE.Vector3();
this.nadir.copy( nadir_ );

// The distance of the directional light from this object and it's target.
// the given north vector is multiplied with this value and the resulting
// vector is the displacement of the directional light from the target.
this.sun_distance = sun_distance_;

// The azimuth of the sun. Starts from the north, clockwise. In radians.
this.azimuth = 0.0;
// The elevation of the sun. Starts from the horizon. In radians.
this.elevation = 0.0;

// Local date and time
this.localDate = new Date();

// The directional light in Three.js is managed by a directional vector.
// To make life easier, I'm adding the light as a child to this hinge object
// and rotating this object in order to set the light's direction
this.hingeObject = new THREE.Object3D();
this.add( this.hingeObject );

// The directional light which is used as the sun light
this.directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(); 
this.directionalLight.castShadow = true;
this.hingeObject.add( this.directionalLight );

// Add the target of the directional light as a child to this object, so
// that it's world matrix gets updated automatically when this object's
// position is changed.
this.add( this.directionalLight.target );
};

SunLight.prototype = Object.assign(
Object.create( THREE.Object3D.prototype ),
{
    constructor: SunLight,

    toJSON: function ( meta ) {
        var data = THREE.Object3D.prototype.toJSON.call( this, meta );
        // TODO
        // not implemented yet
        return data;
    }
} );

// Updates the orientation of the sun using the coordinates and the localDate
SunLight.prototype.updateOrientation = function ( update_date_ = true ) {
// Update the local date if the parameter is true (true by default).
if ( update_date_ ) { 
    this.localDate = new Date();
}

var solarOrientationCalculator = new this.SolarOrientationCalculator();

var sunOrientation = solarOrientationCalculator.getAzEl(
        this.coordinates.x,
        this.coordinates.y,
        this.localDate
    );
this.azimuth = this._degreesToRadians( sunOrientation.azimuth );
this.elevation = this._degreesToRadians( sunOrientation.elevation );
}

// Updates the directional light based on the sun's orientation and the north
// vector. This is actually done by rotating the hinge object which is the
// parent of the directional light.
SunLight.prototype.updateDirectionalLight = function () {
// If the elevation is less than zero, there is no sun light.
// Starting from 2 degrees, start fading the light
var FADE_OUT_THRESHOLD = 2.0;
var elevationDegrees = (180.0 * this.elevation / Math.PI );
if ( elevationDegrees <= 0.0 ) {
    this.directionalLight.intensity = 0.0;
    return;
} else if ( elevationDegrees <= FADE_OUT_THRESHOLD) {
    this.directionalLight.intensity = elevationDegrees / FADE_OUT_THRESHOLD;
} else {
    this.directionalLight.intensity = 1.0;
}
// Reset the hingeObject's quaternion
this.hingeObject.quaternion.copy( new THREE.Quaternion() );

this.directionalLight.position.copy( this.north );
this.directionalLight.position.multiplyScalar( this.sun_distance );
var rotator = new THREE.Quaternion();
rotator.setFromAxisAngle( this.east, this.elevation );
this.hingeObject.quaternion.premultiply( rotator );
rotator.setFromAxisAngle( this.nadir, this.azimuth );
this.hingeObject.quaternion.premultiply( rotator );
}

SunLight.prototype._degreesToRadians = function ( degrees_ ) {
return ( degrees_ % 360.0 ) * Math.PI / 180.0;
}

// ---
// Methods for calculating the Sun's orientation go below
// ---

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator = function() {
this.a = "some val";
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype.getAzEl =
function( lat_, lon_, date_ = new Date() )
{
var jday = this._getJD( date_ );
var tl = this._getTimeLocal( date_ );
var tz = date_.getTimezoneOffset() / -60;
var dst = true;
var total = jday + tl/1440.0 - tz/24.0;
var T = this._calcTimeJulianCent( total );
sunOrientation = this._calcAzEl( false, T, tl, lat_, lon_, tz );
return sunOrientation;
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._getJD = 
function( date_ = new Date() )
{
var docmonth = date_.getMonth() + 1;
var docday = date_.getDate();
var docyear = date_.getFullYear();
if ( (this._isLeapYear(docyear)) && (docmonth == 2) ) {
    if (docday > 29) {
        docday = 29;
    } 
} else {
    // 1900 is a known non-leap year
    if (docday > new Date(1900, docmonth, 0).getDate()) {
        docday = new Date(1900, docmonth, 0).getDate();
    }
}
if (docmonth <= 2) {
    docyear -= 1;
    docmonth += 12;
}
var A = Math.floor(docyear/100);
var B = 2 - A + Math.floor(A/4);
var JD = Math.floor(365.25*(docyear + 4716)) + 
    Math.floor(30.6001*(docmonth+1)) + docday + B - 1524.5;
return JD;
}

// Returns the current time in minutes without the DST
SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._getTimeLocal = 
function( date_ = new Date() )
{
var totalMinutes = 0.0;
totalMinutes += 60.0 * date_.getHours();
// TODO
// Remove one hour if DST is in effect
totalMinutes += date_.getMinutes();
totalMinutes += date_.getSeconds() / 60.0;
return totalMinutes;
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcTimeJulianCent =
function( jd )
{
var T = (jd - 2451545.0)/36525.0;
return T;
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcAzEl =
function( output, T, localtime, latitude, longitude, zone )
{
var result = { "azimuth": 0.0, "elevation": 0.0 };
var eqTime = this._calcEquationOfTime(T);
var theta  = this._calcSunDeclination(T);
var solarTimeFix = eqTime + 4.0 * longitude - 60.0 * zone;
var earthRadVec = this._calcSunRadVector(T);
var trueSolarTime = localtime + solarTimeFix;
while (trueSolarTime > 1440)
{
    trueSolarTime -= 1440;
}
var hourAngle = trueSolarTime / 4.0 - 180.0;
if (hourAngle < -180) 
{
    hourAngle += 360.0;
}
var haRad = this._degToRad(hourAngle);
var csz = Math.sin(this._degToRad(latitude)) *
    Math.sin(this._degToRad(theta)) + Math.cos(this._degToRad(latitude)) *
    Math.cos(this._degToRad(theta)) * Math.cos(haRad);
if (csz > 1.0) 
{
    csz = 1.0;
} else if (csz < -1.0) 
{ 
    csz = -1.0;
}
var zenith = this._radToDeg(Math.acos(csz));
var azDenom = ( Math.cos(this._degToRad(latitude)) *
    Math.sin(this._degToRad(zenith)) );
if (Math.abs(azDenom) > 0.001) {
    azRad = (( Math.sin(this._degToRad(latitude)) *
        Math.cos(this._degToRad(zenith)) ) -
        Math.sin(this._degToRad(theta))) / azDenom;
    if (Math.abs(azRad) > 1.0) {
        if (azRad < 0) {
            azRad = -1.0;
        } else {
            azRad = 1.0;
        }
    }
    var azimuth = 180.0 - this._radToDeg(Math.acos(azRad))
    if (hourAngle > 0.0) {
        azimuth = -azimuth;
    }
} else {
    if (latitude > 0.0) {
        azimuth = 180.0;
    } else { 
        azimuth = 0.0;
    }
}
if (azimuth < 0.0) {
    azimuth += 360.0;
}
var exoatmElevation = 90.0 - zenith;

// Atmospheric Refraction correction

if (exoatmElevation > 85.0) {
    var refractionCorrection = 0.0;
} else {
    var te = Math.tan(this._degToRad(exoatmElevation));
    if (exoatmElevation > 5.0) {
        var refractionCorrection = 58.1 / te - 0.07 / (te*te*te) +
            0.000086 / (te*te*te*te*te);
    } else if (exoatmElevation > -0.575) {
        var refractionCorrection = 1735.0 + exoatmElevation *
            (-518.2 + exoatmElevation * (103.4 + exoatmElevation *
                (-12.79 + exoatmElevation * 0.711) ) );
    } else {
        var refractionCorrection = -20.774 / te;
    }
    refractionCorrection = refractionCorrection / 3600.0;
}

var solarZen = zenith - refractionCorrection;

result.azimuth = Math.floor(azimuth*100 +0.5)/100.0;
result.elevation = Math.floor((90.0-solarZen)*100+0.5)/100.0;
return result;
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._isLeapYear = 
function( yr )
{
return ((yr % 4 == 0 && yr % 100 != 0) || yr % 400 == 0);
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._radToDeg =
function( angleRad )
{
return (180.0 * angleRad / Math.PI);
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._degToRad =
function( angleDeg )
{
return (Math.PI * angleDeg / 180.0);
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcEquationOfTime =
function( t )
{
var epsilon = this._calcObliquityCorrection(t);
var l0 = this._calcGeomMeanLongSun(t);
var e = this._calcEccentricityEarthOrbit(t);
var m = this._calcGeomMeanAnomalySun(t);

var y = Math.tan(this._degToRad(epsilon)/2.0);
y *= y;

var sin2l0 = Math.sin(2.0 * this._degToRad(l0));
var sinm   = Math.sin(this._degToRad(m));
var cos2l0 = Math.cos(2.0 * this._degToRad(l0));
var sin4l0 = Math.sin(4.0 * this._degToRad(l0));
var sin2m  = Math.sin(2.0 * this._degToRad(m));

var Etime = y * sin2l0 - 2.0 * e * sinm + 4.0 * e * y * sinm * cos2l0 -
    0.5 * y * y * sin4l0 - 1.25 * e * e * sin2m;
return this._radToDeg(Etime)*4.0; // in minutes of time
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcSunDeclination =
function( t )
{
var e = this._calcObliquityCorrection(t);
var lambda = this._calcSunApparentLong(t);

var sint = Math.sin(this._degToRad(e)) * Math.sin(this._degToRad(lambda));
var theta = this._radToDeg(Math.asin(sint));
return theta; // in degree
}


SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcSunRadVector =
function( t )
{
var v = this._calcSunTrueAnomaly(t);
var e = this._calcEccentricityEarthOrbit(t);
var R = (1.000001018 * (1 - e * e)) /
    (1 + e * Math.cos(this._degToRad(v)));
return R; // in AU
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcObliquityCorrection =
function( t )
{
var e0 = this._calcMeanObliquityOfEcliptic(t);
var omega = 125.04 - 1934.136 * t;
var e = e0 + 0.00256 * Math.cos(this._degToRad(omega));
return e; // in degree
}


SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcSunApparentLong =
function( t )
{
var o = this._calcSunTrueLong(t);
var omega = 125.04 - 1934.136 * t;
var lambda = o - 0.00569 - 0.00478 * Math.sin(this._degToRad(omega));
return lambda; // in degrees
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcGeomMeanLongSun = 
function(t)
{
var L0 = 280.46646 + t * (36000.76983 + t*(0.0003032));
while(L0 > 360.0)
{
    L0 -= 360.0;
}
while(L0 < 0.0)
{
    L0 += 360.0;
}
return L0; // in degrees
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcEccentricityEarthOrbit = 
function(t)
{
var e = 0.016708634 - t * (0.000042037 + 0.0000001267 * t);
return e; // unitless
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcGeomMeanAnomalySun = 
function(t)
{
var M = 357.52911 + t * (35999.05029 - 0.0001537 * t);
return M; // in degrees
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcSunTrueAnomaly = 
function(t)
{
var m = this._calcGeomMeanAnomalySun(t);
var c = this._calcSunEqOfCenter(t);
var v = m + c;
return v; // in degrees
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcMeanObliquityOfEcliptic = 
function(t)
{
var seconds = 21.448 - t*(46.8150 + t*(0.00059 - t*(0.001813)));
var e0 = 23.0 + (26.0 + (seconds/60.0))/60.0;
return e0; // in degrees
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcSunTrueLong = 
function(t)
{
var l0 = this._calcGeomMeanLongSun(t);
var c = this._calcSunEqOfCenter(t);
var O = l0 + c;
return O; // in degrees
}

SunLight.prototype.SolarOrientationCalculator.prototype._calcSunEqOfCenter = 
function(t)
{
var m = this._calcGeomMeanAnomalySun(t);
var mrad = this._degToRad(m);
var sinm = Math.sin(mrad);
var sin2m = Math.sin(mrad+mrad);
var sin3m = Math.sin(mrad+mrad+mrad);
var C = sinm * (1.914602 - t * (0.004817 + 0.000014 * t)) + sin2m *
    (0.019993 - 0.000101 * t) + sin3m * 0.000289;
return C; // in degrees
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Actually `SunLight.js` has a dependency of `three.js` which is not loaded before initialization of `SunLight.js`.

Though there are multiple ways to solve this problem.

**One way** is to load the `three.js` before `SunLight.js` in `angular.json` like below.

```
"scripts": [
   "node_modules/three/build/three.min.js",
   "src/services/Sunlight.js"
]
```

**Another way** is to modify `SunLight.js` like below

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
const SunLight = function (
     ...// rest of the SunLight.js code.

export default SunLight;
```

then remove it from `angular.json` and import it like below wherever you want

```
import SunLight from 'src/services/Sunlight'; //path will vary based on it's location
```

By default Angular includes only `*.ts` files. As this is `.js` file, you need to update your `tsconfig.app.json` with file to be included(you can use wild cards if you have more `.js` files).

```
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/services/Sunlight.js"
  ],
```

Comment: Hi Ravikumar, The first solution works. But I can't get the second one to work. It 'gives the following error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'src/services/SunLight'. 'D:/TMP/scanimo_02/scanimo/src/services/SunLight.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Comment: Hi Ravikumar, Many thanks for the help. I tried the second solution With adaptation to the tsconfig.app.json file, but the same error keeps showing on the ts file where I want to use the import. It keeps saying   
Error: src/app/viewer/viewer.component.ts:16:22 - error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'src/services/SunLight.js'. 'D:/TMP/scanimo_02/scanimo/src/services/SunLight.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.   16 import SunLight from 'src/services/SunLight.js';

Comment: I also updated the SunLight.js as follow                                                                  
                                                                                                                                          -> import * as THREE from 'three';

SunLight = function () {}                                                                                                      //Other functions here                                                                                                        
  ->  export default SunLight //placed at the end

Comment: @stickske, I tried and it worked perfectly. not sure what wrong in configurations.

Comment: yes very strange. I'll test in a fresh scene tomorrow. Also tested this without success. https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-vs-jsmodule      I must do something wrong as it keeps asking for a declaration file. Could it be something with the spec.ts or d.ts files?